# Sitecore Page Editor Issues with Move and Add Components

Tags: presentation, placeholders

I have a page with "body" placeholder in which I have kept 10 controller renderings on a page.

When I'm trying to order the component using Page editor or Content editor, the sort order randomly readjusts by itself.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

This is Sitecore 7.5 update 2

---

**-- UPDATE 1--**

The issue is observed with the Page Editor and Content Editor both.

I got an update from Sitecore support as below:

> As for the changing the controls order in the **Page Editor**:
>   The issue is indeed server-side and is related to how XML deltas are
>   built and processed.  I've registered the issue as a bug in the
>   current Sitecore version. I've spent quite some time investigating the
>   root cause of the issue and looking for ways to implement the most
>   practical workaround. Unfortunately, the proper patch would be
>   extremely nontrivial to implement and would require the customization
>   of some deep Sitecore logic, which may affect some other parts of
>   Sitecore in unpredictable ways. The only workaround I can provide you
>   with at the moment is the one, that makes an item use full XML
>   representation of page layout instead of a delta one.
>
> As for the changing the controls order in the **Content Editor-->Layout**
>   Details dialog:
>
> This issue was fixed in 7.2 rev.160123 (7.2 Update-6). Please get more
>   info on the Release Notes page using the reference #388264
>   https://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog/Release%20History%20SC72.aspx
>
> - *Sitecore Support*

Note: Though Sitecore Support says its fixed with Sitecore 7.2 update-6 its not working for me in 7.5 update-2.

---

**-- UPDATE 2--**

From Sitecore Support

> Please let me explain the reasons that this issue persists in Sitecore
>   CMS 7.5 U-2 and at the same time was fixed in Sitecore CMS 7.2 U-6.
>
> The reason of that lays in the fact that actually Sitecore CMS 7.2 U-6
>   (January 26, 2016) has been released after Sitecore CMS 7.5 U-2
>   (February 13, 2015).
>
> I understand that this can look a bit confusing at a first glance, sorry for that.
>
> - *Sitecore Support*

**--Final Update--**  
Sitecore has provided Hotfix which works as expected. Sitecore Support's reference number for Hotfix is **126989**

Comment: Hey. Firstly; this issue looks related to the one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918497/sitecore-page-editor-issues-with-move-and-add-components

Can you check if this applies to you?

If not, can you check if you're getting any javascript issues?  Also; you're sure this happen both in Page Editor and when using Presentation Details in the Content Editor?

Comment: This issue is reproducible in Page Editor as well as Content Editor.

Comment: Unfortunately, 7.5 is not a supported release. So even if the issue was fixed on 7.2u6 there is no guarantee it will ever make it into 7.5. Sitecore officially recommends you upgrade 7.5 solutions as soon as possible. Unless you have an extended support plan, 7.5 will be non-supported by the end of 2017. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/641167

Comment: Sorry I don't get it `7.5 is not a supported release` ?

Comment: Seems they've changed their wording a bit. However; this still applies: For improved functionality, capability, and support, Sitecore strongly recommends that you upgrade to the latest version of the Sitecore Experience Platform. [...] The latest Sitecore XP 8.0 update also includes critical hotfixes that significantly improve stability of this release compared to Sitecore XP 7.5.  Therefore, you should plan to upgrade to Sitecore XP 8.0 and not remain in production on Sitecore XP 7.5. You can download Sitecore XP 8.0 from dev.sitecore.net.

Comment: Lastly I have asked Sitecore Support to provide fix for Content Editor atleast..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45966/discussion-between-harsh-baid-and-mark-cassidy).

Comment: @HarshBaid - You could self-answer this question with the info from your second update, that way if people find this question they can check their Sitecore version and determine what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Summary

To summarise the comments on this question, which provide a reasonable answer.

1. 7.5 does not have the fix applied. 7.2 update 6 does.
2. They recommend upgrading to 8 for improved functionality

> Sitecore strongly recommends that you upgrade to the latest version of the Sitecore Experience Platform. [...] The latest Sitecore XP 8.0 update also includes critical hotfixes that significantly improve stability of this release compared to Sitecore XP 7.5.

3. So two options stay on 7.2 update 6 or upgrade to 8 to get fixes.
4. They are working on Hotfix for Sitecore 7.5 update-2

Comment: They wrote to us that they are working on Hotfix for Sitecore 7.5 update-2 and also gave hint about this Hotfix may affect our future Sitecore upgrades/patches as well.

Comment: Sitecore has provided Hotfix which works as expected. Support reference number I have updated in the question.