# Sitecore components added in random order

Tags: experience-editor

Our setup is like this -

- layout

  - left side placeholder

    - left component 1
    - left component 2
    - left component 3
  - right side placeholder

    - component 2
    - component 3
    - component 1 (added onto standard values)

The components on the left side are added fine in the order they are added. The components on the right side, are not added in the order they are supposed to be.

In the above example, component 1 is added to the standard values of the template. When I go to a item created based on this template and try to add component 2 in the experience editor, after component 1, using the 'Add here' button, it adds it to the correct position, but when I hit save, the component jumps to the first position.

Any subsequent components that I try to add after component 1, get added above the component 1 and that ordering is fine except that component 1 is at the bottom of the list.

I looked into the final renderings or the page item, and this is what it shows -

```
<r xmlns:p="p" xmlns:s="s" p:p="1">
    <d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}">
        <r uid="{08D37535-C300-4842-8B91-63F645E4DEFC}">
            <p:d />
        </r>        
        <r uid="{8E09205A-3722-4307-84C9-9BA9B0DBCB46}" p:before="r[@uid='{E9C82680-4384-44AE-BE78-A05042D44DC4}']" s:ds="{60AD1737-26CB-4694-A452-23DE8F6F5550}" s:id="{50D7380B-6D62-469D-94A6-F761D1CCABB3}" s:par="" s:ph="/content" />
        <r uid="{E9C82680-4384-44AE-BE78-A05042D44DC4}" p:before="r[@uid='{90B0191D-835E-4A94-BE09-404DDE50C21B}']" s:ds="{7B573C37-2442-4F23-B41E-32B278BDF0F0}" s:id="{50D7380B-6D62-469D-94A6-F761D1CCABB3}" s:par="" s:ph="/content" />
        <r uid="{90B0191D-835E-4A94-BE09-404DDE50C21B}" p:before="r[@uid='{ECBE3572-71BA-4811-ADBC-5BC4F1163C85}']" s:ds="{7B573C37-2442-4F23-B41E-32B278BDF0F0}" s:id="{50D7380B-6D62-469D-94A6-F761D1CCABB3}" s:par="" s:ph="/content" />
    </d>
</r>
```

The third  element is component 1 and the ph:before its pointing to is actually pointing to a left side component 2 . I don't think this was ever touched or modified intentionally by someone.

Edit: I checked the standard values and there is no ph:before in the Shared Layout for component 1. It gets added after I another component on the right side.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Any thoughts on where to look?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using? Take a look at this question to see if this applies - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/180/sitecore-page-editor-issues-with-move-and-add-components

Comment: @Kasaku .. that ticket does sound familiar but seems not exactly the scenario we are noticing. We are on version 8.0 update 2.

Comment: The issue is with components of different type or same type.

Comment: Are you using Dynamic Placeholders?

Comment: Yes, we are using dynamic placeholders.